# Search class method wont return index

Tags: java, search

> What I'm trying to accomplish here is two columns with random numbers,
>   one random the other one sorted ascending. After that, it should prompt
>   for a number, then it will search and print the index where this is located.
>   The problem I have is that is not returning neither the index or -1.
>   this what I have so far. Thanks for your time and wisdom.

```
public class SearchArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //generate random numbers

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] number = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            number[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 20);
        }
        // copy numbers

        int[] sortedNumber = new int[number.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            sortedNumber[i] = number[i];
        }

        //sort numbers second column

        Arrays.sort(sortedNumber);
        System.out.printf("%s\t\t%s", "Unsorted Array", "Sorted Array");
        for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("\n%d\t\t\t%d", number[i], sortedNumber[i]);
        }

        //search for number

        System.out.printf("\n%s", "Please enter number to search for: ");
        int search = stdIn.nextInt();
    }

    public static int search(int[] number, int search) {
        for (int j = 0; j < number.length; j++) {
            if (number[j] == search) {
                return j;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your code didn't call `search`. Been a long time since my last java app, but you should call something like `return search(sortedNumber, search);` after that `int search = stdIn.nextInt();`

Comment: Thanks again I'll try that, and post a follow up.

Comment: @fuyushimoya I tried what you said but it outputs an error "int search is already defined in method search" I guess its because i brought it in the search method

Comment: Somehow you just use too many `search` in code, not sure which line makes java thought it's ambiguous, try change `int search = stdIn.nextInt();` to someother name like `searchInput`, or try call the static method by `SearchArray.search(...)`.

Comment: @fuyushimoya I think I got it, i desisted in using a class method and Im using linear search instead. That sould do fine. Thanks for your help.